# .NET API controller to receive PHP post message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am configuring online payment gateway on my website created in .NET and Angular.

When the payment is processed the payment service provider sends a notification to my API.

They provided me with sample PHP code which responds to this message but I struggle with my .NET controller to read the variables. The controller catches the request but it cannot read the variables. There are 6 properties in **PaymentStatusDto** class defined as string. I checked FromRoute and other attributes. Also tried to define input variables separately. Nothing works. The controller returns Ok with text **message = " "**

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**POST action in my controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CheckPaymentStatus")]
[AllowAnonymous]
// POST : /api/Payments/CheckPaymentStatus
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckPaymentStatus([FromRoute] PaymentStatusDto payment) {
    return Ok(new { message = payment.STATUS + " " + payment.AMOUNT+ " " + payment.ID_PAYMENT + " " + payment.ID_ORDER });
}
```

**Sample PHP code**

```
<?php 
/* read variables
$_POST["AMOUNT"]
$_POST["ID_PAYMENT"]
$_POST["ID_ORDER"]
$_POST["STATUS"]
$_POST["SECRET"]
$_POST["HASH"] 

/*do main stuff
```

Comment: If they are POSTing to you I doubt the values will be in the route. What is the definition of the DTO you created? As a last resort you can always do `Request.Form["AMOUNT"]`, etc.

Comment: Change `[FromRoute]` to `[FromBody]`. Does it work?

Comment: I tried with [FromBody] and it returned 415 error code. My bad, it looks like it was the correct approach.
DTO is defined as below. I also tried with float instead of double.



`public class PaymentStatusDto
{
    public double AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public string ID_PAYMENT { get; set; }
    public string ID_ORDER { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string SECRET { get; set; }
    public string HASH { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you make HTTP request with form data from PHP app to your ASP.NET Core API endpoint, you can apply `[FromForm]` attribute to your action parameter, like below, which would help get values from posted form fields and bind to properties of action parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CheckPaymentStatus")]
[AllowAnonymous]
// POST : /api/Payments/CheckPaymentStatus
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckPaymentStatus([FromForm]PaymentStatusDto payment)
{
    return Ok(new { message = payment.STATUS + " " + payment.AMOUNT + " " + payment.ID_PAYMENT + " " + payment.ID_ORDER });

}
```

For more information about how model binding works, please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Crowcoder I caught the variables using Request.Form["AMOUNT"]

The controller POST action looks like below and finally it reads all variables.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CheckPaymentStatus")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        // POST : /api/Payments/CheckPaymentStatus
        public async Task<IActionResult> CheckPaymentStatus()
        {
            var AMOUNT = Request.Form["AMOUNT"];
            var ID_PAYMENT = Request.Form["ID_PAYMENT"];
            var ID_ORDER = Request.Form["ID_ORDER"];
            var STATUS = Request.Form["STATUS"];
            var SECRET = Request.Form["SECRET"];
            var HASH = Request.Form["HASH"];

            return Ok(new { message = AMOUNT+ "; " + ID_PAYMENT + "; " + ID_ORDER + "; " + STATUS + "; " + SECRET + "; " + HASH });
        }
```